# Query replace inside region in emacs under OSX Lion

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, osx-lion, replace

I'm using emacs in terminal under OSX Lion, and for some reason I can't search and replace within the active region. The mark seems to be working, i.e. if I set the mark `Ctrl-<space>` and then move forwards I can kill the active region. But if I set the mark, move forwards, and then issue a `Meta-x` `query-replace` command it will cycle through all matching strings from where my cursor is to the end of the file (as if I didn't have an active region marked).

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

<strike>I'm using GNU Emacs 22.1.1, and I installed it via macports.</strike>

I was using GNU Emacs 22.1.1 which came bundled with OSX. I installed GNU Emacs 23.4.1 from macports and problem solved!

Comment: Emacs 22.1.1 is five years old. You should update to either the latest stable 23, or pretest 24. You can get them from http://emacsformacosx.com/

Comment: Excellent. I'll make it a proper answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs 22.1.1 is five years old.

http://emacsformacosx.com/ always has the latest stable, pretest, and nightly builds.

You should update to either the latest stable release of 23, or the latest pretest release of 24 (which is also generally very stable).